# Contact Dashboard permissions

Tags: activities, groups, user-dashboard

We have had the CiviCRM contact dashboard operational for a while, showing only Membership and Contribution data.  However we now want to show assigned activities as well. I ticked the checkbox and checked the dashboard in a non-admin account (admin works great) but I get a permission error. The stacktrace shows a permission error here:

/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php:2259

> ```
> // get all the groups that this user can access
> ```

```
// if they dont have universal access
$groupNames = civicrm_api3('Group', 'get', [
  'check_permissions' => TRUE,
  'return' => ['title', 'id'],
  'options' => ['limit' => 0],
]);
```

I can't decipher from here what permission I am missing that would allow authenticated users to view activities on the contact dashboard.

Comment: What version is this?  There have been some recent changes around mailings.